# Promise must be async - Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, observable, es6-promise

I would like to upload an array of files separately and then post other data only if the files are done. So far, each file uploads with its own request, but I can't make the other requests wait for the files to finish uploading - they all execute at the same time, despite the async/await.

Here is a simplified version of my code (where `run()` needs to be an observable or promise and `postOtherDatas()` needs to wait `uploadFileList()` to be done):

```
public async run(data: Data): Promise<Object> {
    await this.uploadFileList(data.files); // run this first
    return this.postOtherDatas(data.otherData).subscribe(); // run this only if uploadFileList() is done
}
    
public async uploadFileList(files: File[]) {
  return await Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
    this.uploadFile(file).subscribe();
  }));
}

public uploadFile(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `apiUrl/postfile`, 
    formData, { withCredentials: true });
  return this.http.request(req);
}
  
public postOtherDatas(formData: FormData) {
  return this.http.post('apiUrl/postotherdata',
    formData, { withCredentials: true }
  );
}
```

I also tried this but `postOtherDatas()` is never called:

```
public run(data: Data): Observable<Object> {
   return this.uploadFileList(data.files).then(() => this.postOtherDatas(data.otherData).subscribe())
}
```

Comment: I'd use `forkJoin` form RxJs. Also you can `.then` a `promiseAll` and call the method you like in it. Also, `Promise.then` is a void, `Observable.subscribe` is a `Subscription`, not an Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rxjs subscription is not a promise:

```
public async uploadFileList(files: File[]) {
  return await Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
    // Not a promise!
    this.uploadFile(file).subscribe();
  }));
}
```

If you want to keep using promises, you can do it this way:

```
public async uploadFileList(files: File[]) {
  return await Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
    return this.uploadFile(file).toPromise();
  }));
}
```

The same needs to be done in your `run` method:

```
public async run(data: Data): Promise<Object> {
    await this.uploadFileList(data.files); // run this first
    return this.postOtherDatas(data.otherData).toPromise(); // run this only if uploadFileList() is done
}
```

However: I would propose you use rxjs more deliberately, it has some great tools for handling more complicated asynchronicity. E.g. Promise.all can be achieved using the [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) function.